# insert_all does not create auto generated inserted_at with ecto 2.0

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

```
# mix.exs
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.1.4"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0.0-rc"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.9"},
      ...
    ]
  end
```

The installed ecto version is `"2.0.0-rc.5"`

```
iex(1)> categories = [%{name: "stackoverflow", url: "stackoverflow.com"}]

iex(2)> App.Repo.insert_all App.Category, categories

** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (not_null_violation): null value in column "inserted_at" violates not-null constraint

    table: categories
    column: inserted_at

Failing row contains (1, stackoverflow, stackoverflow.com, null, null).
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:176: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:350: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.insert_all/8
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:42: Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert_all/6
iex(2)>
```

From the docs, it seemed the `inserted_at` was autogenerated. Should I've to manually do this part?

```
schema "categories" do
 field :name, :string
 field :url, :string

 timestamps
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Ecto.Schema.timestamps/1](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.0-rc.5/Ecto.Schema.html#timestamps/1) function defines the `inserted_at` and `updated_at` columns. There is a function with the same name in the migrations.

You can either set this at the database level by using:

```
alter table(:categories) do
  modify :inserted_at, :utc_datetime, default: fragment("NOW()")
end
```

Or you can set it in your map:

```
categories = [%{name: "stackoverflow", url: "stackoverflow.com", inserted_at: Ecto.DateTime.utc}]
```

Whichever solution you pick, you will likely have to do the same for `updated_at`.

If you don't want to track the timestamps then you can remove `timestamps` from your schema and drop the columns in a migration (or if you have not committed the migration to version control, just delete the `timestamps` function).

Comment: Thank you. Got error for `updated_at` now. Fixed it with the one suggested above.

Comment: the :datetime type in migrations is deprecated, please use :utc_datetime or :naive_datetime instead

Answer (score 1):

From the [insert_all documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_all/3):

> ... **timestamps, won’t be autogenerated** when using `insert_all/3`. This
>   is by design as this function aims to be a more direct way to insert
>   data into the database without the conveniences of `insert/2` ..